# change phone number in asp identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have problem with updating of phone number in my ASP net core application.
All fields except phone number are saving in DB. I tried 3 different ways to update phone:

- set manualy
- use UserManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync()
- use UserManager.ChangePhoneNumberAsync() with token generation
  All of them are not working. And there are no any errors. Help me please

[HttpPost][AllowAnonymous]

```
public async Task UpdateLogin(UpdateAccountRequest request)
{
    try {
        var user = await UserService.FindExistingUserAsync(request.CurrentEmail, request.CurrentPhoneNumber);
        var account = user.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(x = > x.AccountId == request.AccountId);
        account.FirstName = request.PatientFirstName;
        account.LastName = request.PatientLastName;

        var changePhoneNumberToken = await UserManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(user, request.UpdatedPhoneNumber);
        var changePhoneResult = await UserManager.ChangePhoneNumberAsync(user, request.UpdatedPhoneNumber, changePhoneNumberToken);
        if (!changePhoneResult.Succeeded) {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, changePhoneResult.Errors);
        }

        var updateResult = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

        if (!result.Succeeded) {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        }

        return Ok("User updated");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem disappeared. Loks like DB was not updated